# Is it safe to run multiple instances of bazel-remote pointing at the same NFS directory?

Tags: bazel

I am attempting to use [`bazel-remote`](https://github.com/buchgr/bazel-remote) to perform [Bazel Remote Caching](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/remote-caching.html) on a set of CI servers that share an NFS server.
I cannot use a disk cache because the project I am building is built in Docker.

My current approach is to dynamically start instances of `bazel-remote` when CI runs, and serve the NFS path. That means if multiple builds run concurrently, multiple instances of `bazel-remote` will be running (on different machines and ports), while serving the same directory.

**Is it safe to run multiple instances of bazel-remote pointing at the same NFS directory?**

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this- in order for the disk usage estimation to work, bazel-remote assumes that it's the only process adding files to the cache directory, and it will under-count disk usage if you run multiple bazel-remote instances using the same cache dir.

It would be better to run a single bazel-remote instance somewhere.